# Oracle-ADF inlineFrame initializing view scoped bean twice

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, oracle-adf

*Oracle ADF 12.1.2, Java 1.7, Oracle WebLogic 12.1.2*

I am facing strange issue related with `af:inlineFrame` component. Trying to display/render ADF page inside of `af:popup` within `af:inlineFrame` component. The weird thing is when the popup displayed; view scoped bean's `@PostConstruct` method called twice. That means bean is initialized twice. However it needed to be initialized once since bean is referenced from the page that is going to be displayed inside `af:inlineFrame`.

Correct flow gotta be:

1. Click to button `openPopup()` method called.
2. `openPopup()` sets URI then opens popup.
3. `inlineFrame source` property set as it's going to display `framePage.jspx`.
4. JSF scans `framePage.jspx` code finds out there is a reference to `FrameBean` inside `af:outputLabel`
5. Construct `FrameBean` then call `@PostConstruct` method.
6. Call appropriate getter and render page.

What happens in my case:

1. Click to button `openPopup()` method called.
2. `openPopup()` sets URI opens popup.
3. `inlineFrame source` property set as it's going to display `framePage.jspx`.
4. JSF scans `framePage.jspx` code finds out there is a reference to `FrameBean` inside `af:outputLabel`
5. Construct `FrameBean` then call `@PostConstruct` method.
6. Call appropriate getter and render page.
7. Construct `FrameBean` then call `@PostConstruct` method.
8. Call appropriate getter and render page.

Popup located like:

```
<af:popup id="mainPopup" binding="#{mainBean.mainPopup}">
    <af:dialog id="mainDialog">
        <af:inlineFrame source="#{mainBean.URI}">
        </af:inlineFrame>
    </af:dialog>
</af:popup>
```

Showing popup via `af:button action="#{mainBean.openPopup}"`:

```
public void openPopup() {
    this.setURI("http://localhost:7001/app/framePage.jspx");
    RichPopup.PopupHints hints = new RichPopup.PopupHints();
    this.getMainPopup().show(hints);
}
```

framePage.jspx:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" version="2.1"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:af="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/faces/rich">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
    <f:view>
        <af:document title="Frame Demo" id="demoDocument">
            <af:form id="demoForm">
                <af:outputLabel value="HELLO Common user!"></af:outputLabel>
                <af:outputLabel value="#{frameBean.commonId}">   </af:outputLabel>
            </af:form>
        </af:document>
    </f:view>
</jsp:root>
```

FrameBean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class FrameBean {
    private String commonId;

    @PostConstruct
    public void afterInit() {

    }

    public String getCommonId() {
        return commonId;
    }

    public void setCommonId(String commonId) {
        this.commonId = commonId;
    }
}
```

Making `FrameBean` `@SessionScoped` solves this issue since bean is kept with session but I don't want to keep it within session. Also setting `source` property of `af:inlineFrame` in jspx as hardcoded not fixing the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how 'in-depth' was CDI tested with ADF, but surely is not the most common way of using ADF - at least all ADF documentation goes old-fashion way. I tried myself to enable CDI in one of my projects, but I got errors by following this blog:

http://www.jobinesh.com/2014/08/enabling-cdi-in-adf-applications.html

Furthermore, 
you are using inline frames, which is another uncharted territory. From a  design best-practice perspective, you should 'think in page flows', so instead of using an inline frame, you may use a task-flow-opening-as-dialog, task flow containing framePage.jspx. More about it, here: https://blogs.oracle.com/DavidGiammona/entry/task_flow_call_activity_run_as.

I know this doesn't answer directly to your question, please take it as a general note.

Comment: Thanks Florin actually I am not that experienced with ADF nor capable to decide on a design flow for an ADF app currently, beside that my colleagues are referring that they are used to work with task-flows which consumes memory a lot. That is why I gotta stick with this solution and digg more to make it work.

Comment: "Task flow consuming memory a lot" - I would question this statement as we at RedSamuraiConsulting are constantly monitoring large ADF production applications, but we never came to this conclusion. Indeed, ADF applications may consume large amounts of memory, but that has nothing to do with the task flows.

Just another ADF Myth, in my opinion.

Comment: This is a session we had http://www.slideshare.net/andrejusb/mythbusters-42472692 debunking such mythology.